# Create XMLNodes using DOMDocument

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I'm trying to create XML Files with PHP. I can create normal nodes like:

```
<node>
    <subnode>Value</subnode>
</node>
```

But now I want to create a node with information in the name of the node like:

```
<node information="value">Value</node>
```

How can I do that using PHP and the DOMDocument?

Thanks

Comment: you should have a look into the documentation. This is very well described via "attributes"

Comment: Ok, I found the solution on http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.setattribute.php

Comment: can you specify? how subnode and information attribute are related??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$domDocument = new DOMDocument('1.0', "UTF-8");
$domElement = $domDocument->createElement('field','some random data');
$domAttribute = $domDocument->createAttribute('name');

// Value for the created attribute
$domAttribute->value = 'attributevalue';

// Don't forget to append it to the element
$domElement->appendChild($domAttribute);

// Append it to the document itself
$domDocument->appendChild($domElement);

?>

Will output:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<field name="attributevalue">some random data</field>
```